# Create an Editor Template for DateTime with three input fields for day, month, year, in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, datetime, datetimepicker

I would like to create an editor template for DateTime? field that has 3 text boxes for day, month, year.  Currently my EditorTemplates/Date.cshtml looks like this:

```
@Html.TextBox(string.Empty, Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.Day.ToString() : "",
                            new { @class = "day-box", title = "day", min = "1", max = "31", type = "number" })
@Html.TextBox(string.Empty, Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.Month.ToString() : "",
                            new { @class = "month-box", title = "month", min = "1", max = "12", type = "number" })
@Html.TextBox(string.Empty, Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.Year.ToString() : "",
                    new { @class = "year-box", title = "year", min = "1900", max = "2020", type = "number" })
```

The obvious problem is that that (as is) the id and name attributes all get set to the same value. I need to append something to those values, and never make it back into my model.

I was hoping that appending _Day to the id, and .Day to the name of the Day input, and likewise for month and year would solve the problem. But I can't see an easy way of doing this.

I was going to use Hidden input for the actual value, then use javascript to update the value of the hidden field each time a value changes in one of my three (d/m/y) textboxes.

So is there a way to get the name and id that MVC is going to use, when I pass in string.Empty?  Using ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlPrefix doesn't seem to give full value.

Is there a better way to do what I want? I can't imagine I am the first to tackle this.

I know there are 3rd party date pickers out there. For the sake of this problem I am not interested in them.

Thanks,
~S

Comment: What about writing the <input> tag manually? Or simply make c# properties for day, month and year?

Answer (score 1):

Had DateTime's Year Month Day are ***settable***, you can just do this on your DateTime.cshtml EditorTemplates

```
@model System.DateTime
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Year) / @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Month) / @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Day)
```

Above isn't possible. DateTime's Year, Month and Day properties are read-only.

What you can possibly do is to just create a separate data type:

```
public struct DatePart
{
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int Month { get; set; }
    public int Day { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get { return new DateTime(Year, Month, Day); } }
}
```

Then do this on your date EditorTemplates

```
@model TestV.Models.DatePart           
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Year) / @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Month) / @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Day)
```

Then just access DatePart's Date(DateTime type) property

Answer (score 0):

You can form date from three field in your custom template with javascript and write it in hidden field that will bind to your Model.Date